# QLPreviewController - Select Object as Default

Tags: swift, arkit, qlpreviewcontroller

When using QLPreviewController to display a `.usdz` 3D Object.

There are 2 viewing modes: AR and Object

By default, AR is selected. I'd like the default selected to be "Object" and would like to also disable the Switch so that they can't view it in AR mode. Is this possible?

[image]
[image]

Here is my subclassed `QLPreviewController`:

```
import UIKit
import ARKit
import QuickLook


class ARQLViewController: QLPreviewController, 
QLPreviewControllerDataSource {
var fileURL: URL!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    dataSource = self
}

func numberOfPreviewItems(in controller: QLPreviewController) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func previewController(_ controller: QLPreviewController, previewItemAt index: Int) -> QLPreviewItem {
    let item = ARQuickLookPreviewItem(fileAt: fileURL)
    item.canonicalWebPageURL = nil
    return item
}

}
```

Comment: What if you change the extension to `usd` or `usda`?

Comment: I don't think the MIME makes a difference. I think it comes down to the limitations of `QLPreviewController` regardless of MIME. e.g.: others are also having trouble hiding that share button in top right. So, it may be that is is impossible or extremely difficult to modify that customized navbar

Comment: Yes, the QLPreviewController is famously uncustomizable. Maybe changing the extension is not enough, but you could read the file, export as obj or another 3D supported format, and pass that to the preview controller.

Comment: Since QLPreviewController has an awful forced UX. I resorted to viewing using .obj files with Scenekit

Answer (score 0):

As EmilioPelaez mentioned, `QLPreviewController` is uncustomizable.

to view a 3d Object, I am no longer using `.usdz` files, but using `obj` files + SceneKit